# How kafka scales out on a long processing duration

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Assume I have infinite amount of computing power

1. I have 1 topic with 10 partitions
2. I have 1 consumer-group
3. Each event process takes 1 second
4. a large amount of events is starting to be produced to the topic

Now, since processing takes a while, and Kafka consumers within a single group are limited to the number of partitions (in this case = 10)

it leads to the situation where the rate of consumption << rate of events production.

How can I leverage my infinite compute in this use case to increase the rate of consumption?

(to my understanding creating more consumers groups will not resolve my problem as each consumer group will have to start from offset = 0)

Comment: There are few misunderstandings of Kafka architecture in the question. You can have more then ten consumer groups consuming from topic with 10 partitions- you can have at most ten active consumers within single group consuming from topic with 10 partitions. Second thing you are not obligated to read messages from offset 0, auto.offset.reset property is responsible for that, when we are talking about new consumer groups.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka batches records on each poll. By default, that's 500 records, meaning it'll take 500 seconds (over 8 minutes) for the next poll to happen... The default `max.poll.interval.ms` (time required between polls) is 5 minutes. Therefore, at the very least, you need to increase timeouts, or reduce `max.poll.records` around 300.

Alternatively, you can push data into a durable processing queue, and don't sequentially iterate over those polled batches. Confluent maintains a parallel consumer project that can help with that.

Unclear how you came up with only 10 partitions, but adding more will distribute the load further and you can add more consumers.